# In a visual studio database project, after I add new foreign keys to the project how do I stop it from checking the data against those keys?

Tags: database-project

I added a bunch of foreign keys to the database project when previously there weren't any. In the generated sql file (sql/debug/$projectname.sql) I see a part that starts with

```
PRINT N'Checking existing data against newly created constraints';
GO
USE [$(DatabaseName)];


GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_1];

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_2];
```

and on it goes.

How can I stop the database project from generating this section that checks the data against the new constraints? I tried creating the foreign keys using

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table1 WITH NOCHECK
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_1]
FOREIGN KEY (blah)
REFERENCES Table2 (blah2)
```

but no dice. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, there's an advanced option called checkNewConstraints in the Database.sqldeployment properties page under the properties folder. That should do the trick.

Comment: could you please paste the images (screen shots) as I can't find that option in vs2010/2011/2012

Comment: @AnilPurswani this is very weird, I can't find the file anymore either

Comment: The file itself is called Database.sqldeployment and it is found in the properties folder. You used to be able to expand the properties folder in the database project and click on the file, but, no longer it seems!

Comment: In VS 2013 you can find this option opening the properties of project. In Debug tab, there is a session "Deployment Option" and an "Advanced" button at the end that opens the Advanced Deployment Settings. On general tab you'll find the option "Script validation for new constraints".

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019, you can find it as given in screenshot below. Uncheck the "Script validation for new constraints".

Right click your project and you will find Publish in the context menu. That will open up the Publish Database dialog. Follow 1, 2, and 3 (uncheck this option) and you will be able to get through the validation of existing data in the table for constraint checks.

[image: Disable Check Constraints for existing data in the SQL table]